# Approximating Lie groups by finite groups

Tags: gr.group-theory, lie-groups, finite-groups, approximation-theory

How can one approximate compact Lie groups by finite groups?
My wish is something like this:

> Let $G$ be a compact Lie group.
>   There is a sequence of nested finite subgroups $G_n$ so that $G_n\to G$ in the Hausdorff distance.
>   (That is, for every $\epsilon>0$ there is $N$ so that the $\epsilon$-neighbourhood of $G_n$ is $G$ for all $n\geq N$.)

This is true if $G$ is abelian or if we drop all group structure from the statement (working with compact manifolds and finite subsets).
I found a [paper by Turing](http://www.jstor.org/discover/10.2307/1968716?uid=3737976&uid=2129&uid=2&uid=70&uid=4&sid=21105450688723) stating that this indeed fails for all nonabelian connected Lie groups.
**Are there any positive results in the same spirit for nonabelian groups?**

For example, could there be a sequence of finite groups $G_n$ (with suitable metric) which are not necessarily subgroups of $G$ so that $G_n\to G$ in the Gromov-Hausdorff sense?
The exact mode of convergence is not important; I would just like to know if this idea has any hope in general (or for any single nonabelian group).

The best I could come up with is the following:
Let $G$ be a nonabelian, compact, connected Lie group.
Let $\epsilon>0$.
Given $g\in G$, let $T<G$ be a maximal torus containing $g$ and find a finite subgroup $H_g<T$ so that its $\epsilon$ neighborhood covers $T$.
By compactness $\{H_g;g\in A\}$ covers $G$ for some finite $A\subset G$.
This gives the following result, which is weaker than my wish:

> Let $G$ be a compact Lie group.
>   There is a nested sequence $(C_n)$ of finite collections of finite abelian subgroups of $G$ so that $U_n\to G$ in the Hausdorff distance, where $U_n=\bigcup_{H\in C_n}H$ is the union of the finite groups in $C_n$.

In a different direction, I know that every finite group can be embedded in a compact, connected Lie group, but that doesn't seem to be of much help.

Comment: There is no hope for much; look at the classification of finite subgroups of $\mathrm{SO}(3)$!

Comment: I think that for a compact connected Lie group, the generic pair of elements generate a free abelian group of rank 2, dense in the Lie group. Not finite subgroup, though.

Comment: @BenMcKay: Why do you think that a generic pair of elements commutes?

Comment: Presumably @BenMcKay meant 'non-abelian' (in which case this statement is true).

Comment: Sorry, I meant free nonabelian group, thanks.